# How do I stop/start a scheduled task on a remote computer programmatically?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a script that will stop a scheduled task on a remote computer, do some stuff, and then start the schedule task back up.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Here's what I found.

stop:

```
schtasks /end /s <machine name> /tn <task name>
```

start:

```
schtasks /run /s <machine name> /tn <task name>


C:\>schtasks /?

SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

Description:
    Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
    end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system. Replaces AT.exe.

Parameter List:
    /Create         Creates a new scheduled task.

    /Delete         Deletes the scheduled task(s).

    /Query          Displays all scheduled tasks.

    /Change         Changes the properties of scheduled task.

    /Run            Runs the scheduled task immediately.

    /End            Stops the currently running scheduled task.

    /?              Displays this help message.

Examples:
    SCHTASKS
    SCHTASKS /?
    SCHTASKS /Run /?
    SCHTASKS /End /?
    SCHTASKS /Create /?
    SCHTASKS /Delete /?
    SCHTASKS /Query  /?
    SCHTASKS /Change /?
```

Comment: The machine name is optional: `schtasks /end /tn <task name>`

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  is there a way to get the exit code from the process that ran?

Answer (score 5):

**Note:**
["schtasks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schtasks) (see the other, accepted response) has replaced ["at"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Windows%29).  However, "at" may be of use if the situation calls for compatibility with older versions of Windows that don't have schtasks.

**Command-line help for "at":**

```
C:\>at /?
The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"

\\computername     Specifies a remote computer. Commands are scheduled on the
                   local computer if this parameter is omitted.
id                 Is an identification number assigned to a scheduled
                   command.
/delete            Cancels a scheduled command. If id is omitted, all the
                   scheduled commands on the computer are canceled.
/yes               Used with cancel all jobs command when no further
                   confirmation is desired.
time               Specifies the time when command is to run.
/interactive       Allows the job to interact with the desktop of the user
                   who is logged on at the time the job runs.
/every:date[,...]  Runs the command on each specified day(s) of the week or
                   month. If date is omitted, the current day of the month
                   is assumed.
/next:date[,...]   Runs the specified command on the next occurrence of the
                   day (for example, next Thursday).  If date is omitted, the
                   current day of the month is assumed.
"command"          Is the Windows NT command, or batch program to be run.
```

Comment: The at command creates a scheduled task, but I do not believe it can start or stop an *existing* task.

Comment: Hmmm.  "At" does have the ability to "/delete", which "Cancels a scheduled command," but I expected dealing with any already-running process to fall into the "do some stuff" category--since knowing how to stop the process cleanly would depend on the process being stopped.

Answer (score 3):

```
schtasks /change /disable /tn "Name Of Task" /s REMOTEMACHINENAME /u mydomain\administrator /p adminpassword
```

Comment: This doesn't provide answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about `/disable`, and `/enable` switch for a `/change` command?

```
schtasks.exe /change /s <machine name> /tn <task name> /disable
schtasks.exe /change /s <machine name> /tn <task name> /enable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
schtasks /change /ENABLE /tn "Auto Restart" /s mycomutername /u mycomputername\username/p mypassowrd
```